# How do I show data from certain files based on words entered?

Tags: python, file, text-files

I have a program that allows you to enter data and save them into text files. What I am trying to do is have the user enter their name in the beginning, then whatever data they enter is saved to that name, so when they enter that same name again, it will show the data. But when a new name is entered, there will be no data.

## Name entering prompt

```
name=input("Enter name:")
```

## Below allows the user to enter data and save it into a text file when this function is called

```
def enterproduct():
    number=input("enter food: ")

    price=input("enter calories in food consumed: ")

    # should remove any leading or trailing spaces
    number = number.strip()
    price = price.strip()

    # write data to the file as one line (comma delimited)
    line =number+","+price+"\n" #put all the data together
    with open("inventory.txt","a") as file:
        file.write(line) #write product data
    file.close()

enterproduct()
```

## Below allows you to see the data entered into the text files when called

```
def seeproducts():
    print("ENTERED DATA")
    print("....................")
    products=[] 
    file = open("inventory.txt", "r")
    for line in file:
        products.append(line)
    file.close()

    for item in products: 
        print(item)
        currentline = item.split(",") #split data where there is a comma
        prodnumber = currentline[0]
        price = currentline[1]

seeproducts()
```

Above is just a small example of my code, there are multiple text files created in other parts of the program, you can see the whole thing here: https://pastebin.com/KsdqfBA9

I expect the output to be:

```
*Enter name: matt<br>
enter food: apple<br>
enter calories: 50*

*ENTERED DATA<br>
.............<br>
apple,50*
```

Then when I restart the program and enter matt again:

```
*Enter name: matt<br>
enter food: orange<br>
enter calories: 30*

*apple,50<br>
orange,30*
```

As seen above, the program has saved "apple,50" to matt. But if I enter a new name, it should not show "apple,50"

With the code shown here, I am getting an output that does not save the data attributed to the names, instead, it saves everything regardless of name entered.

Comment: This is not a python specific problem. You're trying to code a database engine. Why not having a look at an already existing one and freely available like sqlite ?

Answer (score 0):

The name is not saved into the same line as the product or the calories.

You could change that by saving the products by adding the name to the filename.
Or by adding the name to your saved line.